# Trying to Update PHP Version through .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update my sites php version (self hosted site). I have read up on all the posts about doing this through the `.htaccess` file but I haven't had any luck. I am using Filezilla to access my sites files.

Comment: The `.htaccess` file is a feature of Apache web server and has nothing to do with your PHP version.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty much a noob when it comes to this stuff. Is there anyway I can update the PHP version though? I do not have cPanel

Comment: How to update PHP varies greatly depending on your server configuration, there's no definitive way to answer that.

Comment: You'd have to first to tell us what OS/distribution you are using before someone could accurately tell you how to do it.

Comment: when you say "self hosted", you mean on a server you manage? Or what?

Comment: @AlexHowansky - is it not possible to change the PHP version that's being used by adding something like `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php` to `.htaccess` as long as the system has `mod_php`?

Comment: @Xhynk Depends on the system configuration. Note there's a significant difference between instructing Apache to launch a version of PHP that's already installed, versus actually installing a new PHP version on the system. I had been presuming OP desired the latter, perhaps not?